# HTML Validator marks my Character Encoding as unsupported

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have a simple HTML5 document and I cannot seem to figure out why the character encoding keeps being marked as wrong by the validator

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

[Error image from the validator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiSy8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in your question should work.. in your image you used `uft-8` instead of `utf-8`. That's the problem

Comment: What a silly mistake. Thank you @Ramkumar G.